# Как передаются данные в домашнем роутере

Tags: сеть, роутер, маршрутизатор, arp

Всем привет, хотелось бы узнать то, как домашний роутер передаёт данные в рамках частной подсети.
Мой домашний роутер является маршрутизатором подсети 192.168.3.0. Вопрос: как в нём происходит передача данных на канальном уровне. Например, как передаются сообщения протокола ARP?
Ведь сообщения протокола ARP состоят из кадра Ethernet + заголовка и данных протокола ARP, поэтому как мой домашний маршрутизатор отправляет широковещательные ARP запросы на все устройства в сети, если в ARP-запросе отсутствует IP-пакет? Каким образом происходит доставка ARP-ответа, в котором уже будет указано, какой MAC-адрес имеет получатель, если в данном сообщении опять-таки отсутствует IP-пакет?
Каким образом роутер передаёт подобные данные? Как коммутатор?

Comment: Снифер трафика и wireshark ну и покурить ARP и RARP протоколы

Comment: @JK_Action, так вот и как раз пытался этим делом маяться.
1. Очистил ARP-таблицу на ПК (IP = 192.168.3.10)
2. Использую утилиту ping, пингую IP-адрес 192.168.3.7 (телефон, подключенный к точке доступа домашнего роутера)
3. Идёт ARP-запрос, у Ethernet кадра получателем указан широковещательный MAC-адрес FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
4. Прошло несколько запросов, получаю ответ с отправителем = MAC-адрес телефона, с получателем = MAC-адрес сетевухи ПК
5. .... Передача ICMP ....
Вопрос остаётся тем же: как внутри роутера передаются все эти Ethernet кадры?

Comment: Честно не силен в сетях, но предположу, что очистив таблицу на ПК, Вы ничего не добились(кроме того, что сетевая подсистема пошла ее перезапрашивать). Вам надо весь трафик снять, что бы разобратся.